# node-sass-middleware add node_modules

Tags: node.js, sass

I'm currently creating a web app that requires sass as my stylesheet language. Is there anyway to import files from `node_modules` without have a ton of relative paths, like `../../../node_modules/`. Namely, I'm attempting to import `material-components-web`, which is under node_modules.

For some apparent reason, no error is thrown nor is anything compiling with what I imported.

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sass = require('node-sass-middleware');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(sass({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    debug: true,
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname), 'node_modules'],
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

styles.sass:

```
@import 'material-components-web'

body
  padding: 50px
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif

a
  color: #00B7FF
```

log:

```
  web:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
GET / 304 324.581 ms - -
  source: /home/samuel/projects/tealist/web/public/stylesheets/style.scss
  dest: /home/samuel/projects/tealist/web/public/stylesheets/style.css
  read: /home/samuel/projects/tealist/web/public/stylesheets/style.css
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 11.999 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css.map 304 0.919 ms - -
```

Comment: I literally can't even get this module to work. Are you tied to it?

Comment: @1252748 it worked so badly, I eventually just switched to gulp compiling it for me.

Comment: I do have it working now. If you are still interested, I can post an answer.

Comment: I'd be interesting on a working solution with the node-sass-middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes fixate on getting something working and this was one of those things. I tried various other things like switching to webpack and was thinking about trying with gulp, but the below setup works in Express:

app.js

```
const sass          = require("node-sass-middleware");

app.use(
    sass({
        src: __dirname + '/sass', 
        dest: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets',
        prefix:  '/stylesheets',
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname), 'node_modules'],
        debug: true,         
    })
 );

//This must come after the scss\sass set up
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

main.scss

```
// My main Sass file.
$mdc-theme-primary: #f56a6a;
$mdc-theme-secondary: #7f888f;
$mdc-theme-background: #fff;

@import "material-components-web/material-components-web";
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

Folder sturucture:

```
-App
 -node_modules
   -material-components-web
     -material-components-web.scss
 -sass
   -main.scss
 -public
   -stylesheets
     -main.css
```